# Polar integral $\int_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{b r dr}{(r^2+b^2)^{(3/2)}(r^2+a^2)^{(1/2)}}$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

We need to solve above integral which I obtained after manipulation. Now I used $r^2 = u $ to get:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{bdu}{2 (u+b^2)^{(3/2)}(u+a^2)^{(1/2)}}$$
which is converted to:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{bdu}{2 (u+b^2) \sqrt{\left(u+\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}\right)^2}}$$

Now I am having trouble reducing it. Please give only a hint! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Denote $I$ the given integral. Integration by parts leads to a function and an integral that is a constant multiple of $I.$

**Solution** (not accomplished, based on the above hint)

For
$$I(b,a)=\int_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{b r\; dr}{(r^2+b^2)^{(3/2)}(r^2+a^2)^{(1/2)}}$$ apply integration by parts considering $u(r)=\frac{1}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$ and $v '(r)=\frac{br}{(r^2+b^2)^{3/2}}.$
We get $$I=\left[\frac{-b}{\sqrt{(r^2+a^2)(r^2+b^2)}}\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{b}{a}\int_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{a r\; dr}{(r^2+b^2)^{(1/2)}(r^2+a^2)^{(3/2)}}
$$
$$I(b,a)=\left[0-\frac{-b}{|ab|}\right]-\frac{b}{a}I(a,b).$$ From this we can compute $I(b,a)+\frac{b}{a}I(a,b),$ but just $I(b,a)$ is wanted.

**SOLUTION with Euler's substitution**

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{b r\; dr}{(r^2+b^2)^{(3/2)}(r^2+a^2)^{(1/2)}}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{b r\; dr}{(r^2+b^2)^{2}\cdot {\sqrt{\frac{r^2+a^2}{r^2+b^2}}}}$$

Set $t=\sqrt{\frac{r^2+a^2}{r^2+b^2}},$ then $r^2=\frac{a^2-b^2t^2}{t^2-1},$ consequently $rdr=\frac{t(b^2-a^2)}{(t^2-1)^2}dt$ and $r^2+b^2=\frac{a^2-b^2}{t^2-1}.$ We obtain $$I=\int_{|\frac{a}{b}|}^1 \frac{b}{b^2-a^2}dt,$$ easy to finish.

Comment: I tried this, the terms with power get exchanged, I did not get the constant multiple of $I$! Please help, the powers of the two factors just get exchanged in the second term!

Comment: @user376345 Thank you a lot! I was not at all able to see that!

Comment: Sorry again but after trying this I still can't get bI/a, if you can explain then I'll be glad!

Comment: I hope there are no mistakes. Deleting my comments, everything is in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried another method of using first $u^2 = r^2+a^2$ and then using $ u = \sqrt{b^2-a^2} \tan v$. If i assume b>a>0 then I get $\frac{2\pi}{a+b}$ as answer!